# Netbeans 8.0.1 not starting after update (linux)

Tags: netbeans

I am using netbeans 8.0.1 on Kubuntu (Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS) and I just installed some netbeans updates due to having a popup telling me to. When I restarted netbeans, it wouldn't launch anymore. If I try to start it over the command line I get this Error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.netbeans.Main
```

Is there a way to fix it without reinstalling it? Reconfiguring will take ages.

Comment: Seems to be a known error where some JARs are not unpacked during installation: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=248643. I would try to have a look at the fix and try to unpack the JARs manually.

Comment: That seems to be the right thing to do, but its all different for me, because he is using Mac. I don't have any unpacked jars in my platform/lib folder

Comment: Then I would try what fscherrer suggested: installing the current version (8.0.2) and let Netbeans pick up your old configuration.

Comment: I did that now, should I tag it as the solution? Its working but its the ugly way to fix this.

Comment: I would tag the answer fscherrer as the solution. And yes, not the nicest way to solve this but better then searching for days for a "clean" solution, or?

Comment: When unzipping the OS independent zip file, the /platform/lib/ was empty - causing this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a comment about this:

> Is there a way to fix it without reinstalling it? Reconfiguring will take ages.

The IDE configs are stored at ~/.netbeans/*version* dir, so, uless you have changed things in *installation_path*/etc/netbeans.conf (like *netbeans_jdkhome* and system properties *netbeans_default_options*), you should be safe to reinstall it with no problem. And, of course, you can always make a copy of the current installation.